# Ratchet WebSocket - send message immediately

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I have to do some complicated computing between sending messages, but first message is sent with second after computing. How I can send it immediately?

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\WSServer;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class CommandManager implements MessageComponentInterface {

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        //...
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $connection) {
        //...
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $connection, $msg) {
        //...
        $connection->send('{"command":"someString","data":"data"}');

        //...complicated computing
        sleep(10);
   
        //send result
        $connection->send('{"command":"someString","data":"data"}');
        return;
    }
}
```

Starting server:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
              new HttpServer(
                  new WsServer(
                      $ws_manager
                  )
              ), $port
);
```

Comment: You could use an EventLoop that runs every millisecond, and your own queue of messages to send.

Comment: It's nice idea, but I think it isn't optimal solution (a lot of iterations, which do nothing). Unfortunately I don't know any better way.

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of a last resort suggestion kind of thing.  Short of overiding some of the core parts of Ratchet.  I suppose you could use symphony to launch a new process to do the computing stuff?

Answer (score 1):

`send` eventually makes its way to React's EventLoop which sends the message asynchronously when it's "ready". In the mean time it relinquishes execution and then the scripts executes your calculation. By the time that's done the buffer will then send your first and second messages. To avoid this you can tell the calculation to execute on the EventLoop as a tick after the current buffers are drained:

```
class CommandMessage implements \Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface {
    private $loop;
    public function __construct(\React\EventLoop\LoopInterface $loop) {
        $this->loop = $loop;
    }

    public function onMessage(\Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg) {
        $conn->send('{"command":"someString","data":"data"}');

        $this->loop->nextTick(function() use ($conn) {
            sleep(10);

            $conn->send('{"command":"someString","data":"data"}');
        });
    }
}

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$socket = new \React\Socket\Server($loop);
$socket->listen($port, '0.0.0.0');

$server = new \Ratchet\IoServer(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new CommandManager($loop)
        )
    ),
    $socket,
    $loop
);

$server->run();
```

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate, would you mind updating it? Seems like they renamed nextTick to futureTick, but even then it still has no effect now